# Can I run binary compiled with C++11 on the platform which doesn't support it?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, c++11

I have 2 similar (say linux) platforms A and B. A supports C++03 and C++11; however B supports only C++03 compiler.

I compile code (with C++03) on platform A and able to run its binary on B without any problem. Is this case true for C++11 also ? (It may work in my platform, but want to know in broader sense).

In other words, is C++11 limited till compilation only or it's also a framework enhancement (added with support for new libraries and threads)?

Comment: In principle I don't think this is any different from, "can I run code from GCC version x.y.z+1 on a distribution which only officially supports x.y.z?". Yes, if the ABI hasn't changed and you can ensure that no new library dependencies are introduced. In practice, implementing C++0x is more likely to introduce new dependencies than the average compiler release, so you have to ask the compiler. C++0x *is* a framework enhancement, but the standard doesn't add anything that's unimplementable on an existing Posix system, so it's an implementation detail whether C++0x relies on new libraries.

Answer (score 7):

In general, yes, but there should be C++0X runtime libraries present on the target machine, or you should have the runtime statically linked into the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Once you have binaries or executable's they should work on any platform. That is the purpose of them in the first place.

Comment: What about the changes to the standard library? Will he be able to link to any shared library implementations of the standard library on Linux?

Comment: Don't think so, you'll probably have to deploy the standard library from your c++0x compiler along with your application's binary

Answer (score 1):

Since C++, whatever version, compiles down to Assembly (and OS-API-calls if dynamically linked), sure can do, as long as the instruction set is supported by the platform (and the proper DLLs are present).

Comment: While assembly is a common target (or intermediary representation) for C++ toolchains, it's not really relevant to distributing binaries.

Answer (score 0):

To contrast the Linux-specific answer:

Windows does not have the notion of "supported C++ platforms". It works the other way around: C++ compilers can target different Windows versions. The C++ runtime for VS2010 supports XP SP2 and later.